# What about a pro/cons definition per answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

I was wondering a possible improvement that to me would be very usefull for the majority, I'd like to know what you'd think about it.

When looking for a solution to a problem I find in code, often I find several different solutions, more often under the same question. So when I face this situations, I could be a, say, "subject newbie" that is trying to fetch clues in order to learn more and this abundance of solutions might be confusing and I could end up using the less suitable solution for my case.

To help me pick the solutions that most fits in my needs, I would find very helpfull a sort of answer subsection (like comments but togglable - design free for discussion) where users can contribute with "pros" and "cons" about the specific solution. So if "pros" fits and "cons" are negligible, then that's my solution.

**Example:**

for the sake of clarity I'll give an example.

When searching how to implement HTTPS communication in an app, I found two solutions:

1. make the app believe that every SSL certificate is valid not givining it any key.
2. add your SSL certificate to the trusted certificates.

both solutions achieve the target, but both have pros and cons.

**Solution 1**:

- *pros:* simple to implement
- *cons:* extremely unsecure, not suitable for production systems

**Solution 2**:

- *pros:* most secure
- *cons:* more difficult to implement

I don't have points about the design on how to do it, so everyone can put its coin.

Do you think this could be of any help?

Comment: Note that downvoting on feature requests isn't necessarily to say "this is a bad contribution", but can simply be "I disagree that this feature should be implemented"!

Comment: Pros and cons are often opinion based ...

Comment: Uhm...sounds like a bad idea :)

Answer (score 8):

There's no need for this.

In well-answered questions, you will see this already being done, using the tools available.

- Answerers already do this by mentioning pros/cons in their answer (you will notice good, experienced answerers doing this often)
- other users can point out advantages and weaknesses in comments

A subsection would just add clutter to the UI, plus it is very unlikely it would be useful in a lot of cases: there aren't actually *that* many Q&A's where there are advantages and disadvantages that can be distinctly presented in the way you envision.

It is also extremely unlikely these "pro" and "con" fields would be utilized so frequently that they actually have some large-scale positive impact. To generate a really good "pros" and "cons" list, someone experienced would have to put a lot of thought into evaluating each answer.

Comment: I know that comments and well-answered answers point these things, but I tought of a "methodic" way to have those informations and I see also that more often I catch "lazy" answers that don't point these things out. I don't agree on the "unusefulness", but I understand your point. (Another application could be pointing out API level requirements for Android for example)

Comment: You can't force people to add this kind of information to answers. Especially since it often doesn't even apply to a answer.

Comment: ^^ you can try, the result would be far fewer answers.