# How to revisit the use of pros/cons to format discussion

Tags: support, meta, discussions-space

The use of **pros and cons** has already been proposed more than once. One instance of something like this was proposed [11 years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124516/1359324) on Meta Stack Exchange, more recently here we had [Asking for thoughts vs listing pros and cons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377270/21769175).

Almost any idea / feature request related to these concepts was "rejected" in one way or another because Stack Overflow didn't have discussions, but now, at least as an experiment, it has them.

Let's say that I want to work on a proposal similar to those done in the past about pros and cons that I want to adapt to "Discussion Space" as the Discussion experiment being run on Collectives is recently called.

- How could something like this be discussed / proposed? I.e., support using recent developments on critical thinking, debate, argumentation, and the like.
- Should this be posted as an answer to one of the questions created by [Berthold](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/18279858/berthold) [Staff][Mod] or should be created as a new post using the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [discussions-space](/questions/tagged/discussions-space) tags?

More obvious examples related to pros/cons

- [What about a pro/cons definition per answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300533/21769175)
- [Are all "pros and cons" questions opinion based?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362207/21769175)

Comment: is... there a reason the current discussions feature *cant* support this with it's current features? I don't think i quite understand what you're asking for. Isn't this precisely one of the topics advertised as things discussions is intended for?

Comment: @KevinB I updated the question. Added a statement to join the first statement with the bullets, and rewrited one.

Comment: I do agree that there's no reason not to try this in Discussions now. If there's specific formatting options or tooling that you'd need, those can be feature requests, but in the near term those requests would probably be most useful as places where we discuss workarounds using existing features. I'd say just go for it! Keep me and Sasha in the loop, we're happy to talk more about experimenting and doing what we can to support that.

Comment: @Berthold Please excuse my delay in replying. In a few days, I will scan the [meta-tag:discussion-space] tag to get up to speed on the Discussion feature and return to the activity around this topic. In the meantime please look at [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394718/289691), which was posted a few moments ago on Meta Stack Exchange. I have a chatroom on the Meta Stack Exchange realm that I might use as a point of contact during the following days. If you would like to invite me to a chatroom on [so] I'm open to getting such invitations. I will keep you and Shasha posted.

Answer (score 6):

Discussions existing as a place for these things that aren't acceptable in Q&A format doesn't change that these things aren't acceptable in Q&A format... so I don't see what Discussions existing and accepting this content changes about any of those topics, outside of *some* of them now having a place to exist if they happen to be within a given Collective that also happens to be one of the Collectives being used to test Discussions.

As long as Discussions is still just a test being run on the side for a select few tags with no known roadmap... it's hardly worth revisiting those older discussions.

Comment: Even if we did revisit those discussions... what would the discussion be? "Yea, Discussions was literally built for these useless topics, of course they're on topic there."

Answer (score -1):

In this answer, I include two sections. On the first I will paraphrase the answer given by Berthold in a comment on the second, I will add my understanding of one of his suggestions.

---

## Rephrasing Berthold's comment

1. Things previously rejected, like ideas related to pros and cons, could now be tried in Discussions.
2. Propose them as [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). Still, it might take a while to complete the corresponding process.
3. In the short term, discuss workarounds to implement those things by using existing features.

---

## Section 2

I understand that the existing features to be used are those that are included in the *Discussions* experiment scope, mainly *Collectives* and *Discussions* features. Also, it might be possible to consider other Stack Overflow features already included in the scope of the experiment, like the left panel and the Community Bulletin.

I.E., a *discussion post* might explicitly ask participants to post cons and pros as replies proposing specific rules like a reply should contain only pros or cons, then, reply to reply to post evidence to support or rebuttal the corresponding reply.

The above could be done without requiring any *technical workaround* (userscript, browser extension, update help article and alike). Still, it's very likely to be more successful if a group of users is interested in timely participating in a discussion with these requirements. The workarounds in the short term should be about communication and coordination. It could be helpful if the team had identified users that might be interested in something like this point or highlighted suggestions that require this kind of "soft workarounds" in a similar way as it was done on [Update on Collectives and Discussions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426650/21769175).

For people expecting to see a clear connection with technical stuff, a long-term goal that could be adopted is to have an argument map automatically generated with the assistance of artificial intelligence. There are already works pointed out to achieve this, among other things ArgDown. In the short term, ArgDown could be used in the Discussion Space only as a JavaScript library to extend the markdown support to embed argument maps. In a bit longer term, it would be great if the Discussions Space included a view that automatically shows the argument map of a **structured discussion** based on user classification of posts as claims, support, rebuttal, warrant, etc., depending on argumentation model selected or to be developed by the Stack Overflow community interested on discussions.

Comment: Is there a pro/con discussion post in your area of expertise that you're open to drafting? [This post in NLP](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions/76955830/langchain-vs-llamaindex-with-llms-for-data-ingestion) was a "versus" question, along the same lines. How would you suggest revising it, if this is a good example?